sass mixin - variable hint
lets say I have a mixin with a couple of variables:
@mixin heading($fow: 900, $mb: 1.6rem) {
  font-size: clamp(2rem, 1.3077rem + 3.4615vw, 3.125rem);
  font-weight: $fow;
  margin-bottom: $mb;
  font-family: $headings;
}

is there a way to display a "hint" to show what kind of variables can I change?
@include heading("hint-for-variables")



What kind of hint: in the console, in your IDE? Could you clarify the question?

its in the example... "hint-for-variables"... so inside parentheses
